# Is there a way to send a Gmail message or create a notification when a daily email is not received?

Tags: gmail, gmail-api, incoming-mail

I receive an email that is only important when not received. Is there a way to be alerted that the message is missing?

Answer (score 1):

### This is possible if the email has some kind of identifier, e.g. sender or subject

- You can write e.g. an [Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script) code that runs on daily [trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#time-driven_triggers)
- The script will [search for all inbox threads or messages fulfilling your criteria](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/gmail#list_inbox_snippets)
- You can specify the criteria (such as date, sender, subject etc.) with the search query [q parameter](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/filtering)
- See [here](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/list) for more informaiton about the Gmail API method `Users.messages: list`

> Mind: Filtering messages with a query is best done with the Gmail API,
>   however in order to implement a daily trigger it is convenient to use
>   Apps Script. The Gmail aPI can be easily implemented in Apps Script an
>   an [Advanced
>   Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/gmail).